# Has there been any information about more One-Punch Man episodes being released?

Tags: one-punch-man

I've finished the 12 One Punch Man episodes and the OVA.

As far as I know there aren't any more episodes. Is there any news from a confirmed source about a second season coming?

Comment: There are also 6 (?) special additional episodes (~15 min each) coming out soon (some are already out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there has been no official announcement as to a second season right now. But the manga artist however did tweet the following
[image]

Which does seem to hint to working hard on the second season, of the anime

One punch man was a great hit and got pretty good sales figures, in both manga, anime and figurine sales. So the second season is almost set in stone, but until the actual announcement is made, don't expect to much!

Comment: What does that post say exactly?

Comment: @Luffy Google translate says the following: `Appalling work hard, so you can also make two terms!`

Comment: Roughly, "Working hard on the second season/phase!" It just doesn't say what of.

Comment: @Dimitrimx: Google translate is terrible. It simply says "I will work hard so that second season is animated". And the tweet is not from the creator, it's the JUMP manga artist.

Comment: @nhahtdh Figured it would be a bad translation. Fixed the creator part, I seem to have overlooked that